# How to name each dataframe developed in a for loop by a list value

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a pandas dataframe where I want to filter to 10 different dataframes based on unique values in a column.  I have a list of those values and would like to dynamically name each filtered dataframe by the name it's filtered on.

Here is some example code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'value':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
      'value2':['a','a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','d','d','d','d','e','e','e','e','e','e','e']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)

value2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']

for value in value2:
    value = df1[df1['value2'] == value]
```

So the end result would be five dataframes named for each value in the `list` value2, filtered to all observations from df1 that are also from value2.

Comment: Isn't this same as `df.groupby("value2")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to create a dictionary:

```
dfs = {}
for value in value2:
    dfs[value] = df1[df1['value2'] == value]
```

Then if you want to access them from outside you can simply query `dfs[value]`.